# Devise is not creating a User.rb model when I run the model generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise, mongomapper

```
[WARNING] You provided devise_for :users but there is no model User defined in your application
```

I've done some googling and it seems this is something do with setting up the ORM configuration for devise.rb in config/initializers which I had done:

```
require 'devise/orm/mongo_mapper'
```

Is there something I am missing?  What do I need to do to get the Devise generators to work with mongomapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to set

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.orm = :mongo_mapper
  ...
end
```

in your initialiser as well.